# How to use R to plot $f_n(\theta)$ based on following samples?

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, likelihood, qq-plot

For iid random samples $X_1,\dots, X_n$ with mean value $E X_1=\theta$, take $X_{(1)}=\min \{X_1,\dots, X_n\}$ and $X_{(n)}=\max \{X_1,\dots, X_n\}$. If $\lambda$ solves equation
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{X_i-\theta}{1+\lambda(X_i-\theta)}=0
$$
for $\lambda\in [\frac{1/n-1}{X_{(n)-\theta}}, \frac{1/n-1}{X_{(1)-\theta}}]$.

Let
$$
f_n(\theta)=-\sum_{i=1}^n\log(1+\lambda(X_i-\theta))
$$

How to use R to plot $f_n(\theta)$ with $\theta\in [1,12]$ based on following code?

```
# I first get 100 samples 
set.seed(201111)
x=rlnorm(100,0,2)

#theta is the mean of x
theta=mean(x)
n=100
xmax=max(x)
xmin=min(x)
# I define function h, and use unifoot function to find lambda
h=function(lam, n)
{
 sum((x-theta)/(1+lam*(x-theta)))
}
uniroot(h, c((1/n-1)/(xmax-theta),(1/n-1)/(xmin-theta)),n=n)$root
```

But how to plot `f_n(theta)' like [image]?

Based on the code in answer, I got the following point plot.
[image]

Comment: You computed a single solution for $\theta = \bar{x}$. What you probably need to do is compute also for other values of $\theta$. Then you get a vector which you can plot.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus But I got a point plot? How to get a profile plot of `f_n`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a sequence that goes from 1 to 12 at whatever granularity you desire, use a for loop to compute 'f_n(theta)' at each point in the sequence, storing the results in a vector. Then at the end plot that vector, and it will give you a plot of 'f_n(theta)' over [1,12]. You can create a sequence with the seq() function.

```
theta_seq = seq(from = 1, to = 12, by = 0.01)
```

I'd also ask though, is $\theta$ supposed to be $E(X_1)$ or $\bar{X}_n$? If the former, I'd interpret your example as needing to have

```
theta = 0
```

rather than

```
theta = mean(x)
```

You could ultimately get something like this

```
set.seed(201111)
theta_seq = seq(from = 1, to = 12, by = 0.01)
f_n = rep(NA, length(theta_seq))

# I define function h, and use unifoot function to find lambda
h=function(lam, n)
{
 sum((x-theta)/(1+lam*(x-theta)))
}

f_n = rep(NA, length(theta_seq))
i = 1
x = rnorm(100, 0, 2)
n=100
xmax=max(x)
xmin=min(x)

for (theta in theta_seq)
{
lambda = uniroot(h, c((1/n-1)/(xmax-theta),(1/n-1)/(xmin-theta)),n=n)$root

f_n[i] = -sum(log(1+lambda*(x-theta)))
i = i+1
}
plot(theta_seq, f_n, type = "l")
```

I get a plot that looks like this

[image]

Comment: $\theta$ is the mean of $X$.

Comment: Can I ask if the code for function $h(x)$ correct? I am not sure about the R code for sum. Do we need the index for sum from i=1 to n and the index of x?

Comment: Also, how to plot the profile of $f_n$ but not the point?

Comment: According to your statement of the problem, $\theta = E(X_1)$ the theoretical mean of $X$ which is not the same as $\bar{X}$, the sample mean of $X_1, \ldots, X_n$.

Comment: To get a profile a likelihood, you need to think of the observed data as fixed, and thus generate a single dataset. If that diata is iid draws from $N(0,2)$, then I have modified the code above to do this.

Comment: Thanks! Can you see this question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/568464/how-to-get-a-95-confidence-interval-for-theta-2f-n-theta-le-chi-12?

Comment: Sorry, I just find you use `x = rnorm(100, 0, 2)` but `x=rlnorm(100,0,2)`. Can we transform log-normal `x=rlnorm(100,0,2)` to normal?